# How do I get my dreamweaver site to use my nginx docker container as a web test server?

Tags: nginx, docker, webserver, dreamweaver

I'm new to using docker though I followed the tutorials to create a nginx web server container and I have a website created in Dreamweaver. I was wanting to know how I can use the virtual web server to host my Dreamweaver site as a test server. Can I just open the kitematic and grab a nginx and place my Dreamweaver file into like the 2048 (game) example on there website?

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty broad but in essence you'd want to start with the nginx docker image. Create a `Dockerfile` that copies and configures your dreamweaver app and use the `FROM nginx` directive.

More info [here](https://blog.docker.com/2015/04/tips-for-deploying-nginx-official-image-with-docker/)

Answer (score 0):

I think that using a `FROM nginx` is a bad idea. NGINX is a service on its own and should run within a docker as a stand-alone.

Your website-docker and your nginx-docker should communicate together using [`--link <name or id>:alias`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/#legacy-links).

If you have several websites, you should have several dockers but still only one nginx. So if every websites docker embedded their own nginx that's messy and far away from the best practice...